# How to de-serialize C# list object and iterate through it to parse values in an Ajax success response

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

I call an action method via AJAX and return a list object, I am having difficulty in de-serializing the response in JQuery. I try to iterate through the repsone via $.each function but I get NULL.  I know for sure data returned contains an object.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ToolTips(string viewName)
    {
        List<ToolTipMvc.Models.ToolTipMvcModel> result = ToolTipMvc.Models.ToolTipMvcModel.GetToolTip(viewName);
        var y = result;

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string output = jss.Serialize(result);

        return Json(output);
    }

public static List<ToolTipMvcModel> GetToolTip(string viewName)
{
    List<ToolTipMvcModel> items = new List<ToolTipMvcModel>();
    //items.AddRange(toolTipIds.Select(s => GetToolTip(s)));

    ToolTip tp = new ToolTip();

    ToolTipMvcModel item = new ToolTipMvcModel();
    item.Description = "list item 1";
    item.Field = "ctrlOne";

    ToolTipMvcModel item2 = new ToolTipMvcModel();
    item.Description = "list item 2";
    item.Field = "ctrlTwo";

    items.Add(item);

    return items;
}  
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: toolTipsUrl,
        cache: false,
        datatype: "html",
        data: { viewname: "runCreate" },
        success: function (data) {

alert(data);

                        data = JSON.parse(data);
                        alert(data);
                        $.each(data, function (dt) {

                            var mydata = data.Field;

                            alert(mydata);

                        });
```

}

**EDIT**

When I alert the data I see the JSON being returned for instance

[{"Field: "ctrlTwo", "Description":"List item 2"},{"Field: "ctrlTwo", "Description":"List item 2"}]

but when I use JSON.Parse(data) or $.parseJson(data)  I see object object. I just want interate through and populate some text areas on the page

Comment: So what does the `data` variable contain when your `success` function runs?

Comment: when i try to alert it, it shows object object

Comment: Try using the dev tools in your browser to see what the response looks like, then update your question with that information.

Comment: im sorry i dont know how to look at the ajax response through the dev tools, could you point me in right direction?

Comment: In IE and Chrome, press F12 and go to the Network tab. In IE you will need to enable capture. After that, refresh your page and check the response to your call to Tooltips.

Comment: I wonder if setting `dataType` to html is the problem? This property is used to indicate what you are expecting back from the server - try setting it to JSON and see how that goes. As before, posting the contents of `data` would be very helpful - you will get an answer much faster this way.

Comment: i realized that and changed it to json, thanks for pointing that out, still no luch, in IE8 I dont see a network tab, i see profiler and etc and the things which are not enabled. since the ajax response happens after i open a dialog box, refreshing the page closes the box. Ill find the exact response like you asked and try to update the question. thanks for bearing with me on this issue

Comment: If you have access to Google Chrome, try the code Dalorzo suggested, because you'll be able to view the JSON response in the Console tab.

Comment: I modified my controller action ,Please see my edit. I can see the respone as pure JSON when I alert, but when I try to iterate i see object object, object object since there are two list items returned

Comment: I realize this probably isn't relevant to you this long after the question was asked, but I did notice this following error:

When you define ToolTipMvcModel item2 = new ToolTipMvcModel(); you then assign the values you want to assign to item2 to item instead. The effect of which is you overwrite your item values and don't assign anything to item2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to explicitly use the `JavaScriptSerializer` yourself. The call to `Json` will serialize it for you, so instead have your controller method look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ToolTips(string viewName)
{
    List<ToolTipMvc.Models.ToolTipMvcModel> result = ToolTipMvc.Models.ToolTipMvcModel.GetToolTip(viewName);

    return Json(result);
}
```

Doing this also means that you shouldn't need to perform any explicit `JSON.Parse` or `$.parseJson`.

In your `success` handler, you should be able to iterate through the results as follows:

```
success: function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = data[i];
        console.log(item.Description);
        console.log(item.Field);
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect, very simple solution, i finally got the values parsed through writing each function but your solution is way better so going to use it.